# How to solve ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, iis, windows-firewall

I have recently set my firewall settings to default, and since that moment I can't access the websites hosted on IIS (on my machine or on machines in the same local network as me) from the web browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox). However I can access those machines from whithin windows file explorer. I installed ESET Smart Security which is now controlling my firewall settings. 
NB. Even if I disable the firewall I still get this error.
I'm working on Windows 8.1 Professional edition. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Disable ESET control over your firewall it sounds like it is "protectng" your secured connections, which is causing you problems

Comment: I installed it after I faced the issue, so this can't solve the problem.

Comment: Feel free to try and still disable it though